# Generic Method Fails Explicit Cast

Tags: c#

```
//I know for sure that the animal being passed is a Tiger
protected virtual void Eat<AnimalType>(Animal animal)
where AnimalType : Animal
 {
   //The animal type is a Tiger type.
   //Should be equivalent to :
   //Tiger myDerivedAnimal = animal as Tiger;
   AnimalType myDerivedAnimal = animal as AnimalType;

   if (myDerivedAnimal != null)
   {
       myDerivedAnimal.eat();
   }
}
```

When I'm making the call :

```
Eat<Tiger>(anAnimalThatIsATiger);
```

For some reason the as cast is returning my a null object. I've looked trough the debugger and the animal passed in arguments is an animal with a reference to a tiger, so why is this cast failing to return my my tiger? As of right now myDerivedAnimal is filled with default values(0, null, etc).

Comment: You misuse generics  with `AnimalType : Animal`,  simply get `Animal`.

Comment: If you are casting `animal as AnimalType` wouldn't it be a better idea to change your method signature to `protected virtual void Eat<AnimalType>(AnimalType animal) where AnimalType : Animal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me:

```
  class Animal {
    public virtual void eat()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Animal.eat()");
    }
  }

  class Tiger : Animal {
    public override void eat()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Tiger.eat()");
    }
  }

  class SomethingElse {

    protected virtual void Eat<AnimalType>(Animal animal) 
    where AnimalType : Animal
     {
       AnimalType myDerivedAnimal = animal as AnimalType;

       if (myDerivedAnimal != null)
       {
           myDerivedAnimal.eat();
       }
    }

    public void Test()
    {
      var myTiger = new Tiger();
      Eat<Tiger>(myTiger);
    } // Test
  }

  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      new SomethingElse().Test();
    }
  }
```

when I run it it prints

```
 Tiger.eat()
```

as expected.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this the answer?  This is what Eric and I said, except it propagates the misuse if generics. The generic part of this is never even used...did I miss something?

Comment: @JustinPihony: my answer is exactly as Eric's: I pointed out that the code actually works (I did not get that from you answer...). I suspect that the fact that I used exactly the same class names showed where the class hierarchy of OP was wrong (in the part of code that was not in the question).

Answer (score 7):

This is not how generics work, you want something more like this:

```
protected virtual void Eat<AnimalType>(AnimalType animal)
where AnimalType : Animal
```

The constraint will force it so that it inherits `Animal`. Notice that the parameter type changed from `Animal` to `AnimalType`

HOWEVER, you don't even need generics here by the looks of the code. You can just use inheritance at its root and call

```
animal.Eat()
```

That could be because of the simplification for SO, so at minimum you would not need the cast as this is taken care of by the generic itself:

```
protected virtual void Eat<AnimalType>(AnimalType animal)
    where AnimalType : Animal
 {
   if(animal == null) return;
   animal.eat();
}
```

Comment: Agreed - but why the code as written by the OP does not work..? It is not clear to me

Comment: I've made the change, but now I can't pass in a tiger the compiler is expecting an AnimalType and not an Animal.

Comment: Does Tiger inherit from Animal? That is why you were getting the problem in the as cast (to answer @MiMo). That is the point of a generic constraint, it lets you catch this problem at compile time instead of runtime

Comment: I've edited my question, I messed up. I'm actually passing in the base class and within that object there is a reference to the actual derived class which I'm trying to cast back into it's derived type.

Comment: @Pat You are going to have to provide more code....I may have lost you...it sounds like you are using the base class to store the derived class.....why......?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this code:

```
class P
{
    class Animal {}
    class Tiger : Animal {}
    static void M<T> (Animal animal) where T : Animal
    {
        T t = animal as T;
        System.Console.WriteLine(t == null);
    }
    static void Main ()
    {
       Animal animal = new Tiger();
       M<Tiger>(animal);
    }
}
```

I got `False`. I'm therefore unable to reproduce your problem. **Provide a small, complete program that actually reproduces the behaviour you are describing.** Either you'll find your bug by doing so, or you'll give us something we can actually analyze.

Comment: I'm not passing in a tiger, it should be new Animal()

Comment: @Pat then why are you telling the generic that you are passing in a Tiger....I really think that you need to understand generics better.....

Comment: @Pat: Then "animal is Tiger" should be false and "animal as Tiger" should be null. Why would you expect that an animal that is NOT a tiger should report that it is a tiger?